# MySQL issue: Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, data-dictionary

Recently I have updated from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 and after few weeks the following error message was displayed each time I access the phpMyAdmin application:

> 1146 - Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist

I have investigated the issue to the point where I have been forced to downgrade the MySQL service to 5.0.95 and  then to upgrade the service once again to 5.1.

None of the above outlines steps however resolved the issue and the error message in questions still persist . This error disables me to access any database/table via the phpMyAdmin interface.

The error logs on the server are not providing additional information at all. The checked logs were:

-> mysql.err log 
-> the cpanel error log

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: check your web server error log. you may get more info

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: The version of the phpMyAdmin is 4.0.5 and it has been automatically installed/upgraded by the cPanel service version 11.38.

As for the global errorlog of the server, I have checked /var/log/messages and also the apache error log, however none of these logs contain additional information.

Comment: Actually I have managed to resolve the issue. It is quite a strange one. It seems that Google Chrome default language is causing the issue since phpMyAdmin takes that language and translates itself to it. 

I have changed the language to English and logged out from my google account and the issue was magically resolved. 

Thank you all!

Comment: It's normal that phpMyAdmin tries to use the default language of the browser. Which language was it picking? and if you manually switch back to this language, does the problem come back?

Comment: The language picked by the phpMyAdmin application was Bulgarian, as this was the natively set language for my browser and my google account. Once I have changed this setting back to English the phpMyAdmin application worked properly as usual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL can't select from existing table because it doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044967/mysql-cant-select-from-existing-table-because-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 15):

Run `sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force`

Then restart mysql

i.e. `sudo service mysql restart` or `sudo service mysqld restart` depending on the version and distribution you have

You need to logout of phpMyAdmin then login for the change to take effect.

Comment: this does nothing to help me

Comment: Doesn't do anything

Comment: That's what worked for me. Which version of mysql are you using? Did it happen during an upgrade?

Comment: This worked for me also. Sometimes you need to logout of phpMyAdmin then login for the change to take effect.

Comment: This worked for me AFTER LOGGING OFF and LOGGING ON phpMyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. It can be resolved by reconfiguring phpMyAdmin.

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Close phpMyAdmin page and