# Error upon selecting any database in phpmyadmin; accessible through CLI though

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Could anybody help where the following error in phpmyadmin comes from?

```
#1146 - Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist
```

[image: phpmyadmin error]

It pops up no matter what db I select in the tree. I can press the + though, and select tables. Also, in the CLI I am not witnessing any problems.

I have updated mysql manually to 5.7 (from 5.5 which was shipped with LAMP). Could that be related? As can be seen from the following screenshot,

[image: different versions]

there is a discrepancy between the db client version and server version. Again, I am not witnessing problems in the CLI.

**Edit (additional info)**
This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756908/mysql-database-browsers-not-working-after-upgrade seems to be very much related to my case. Also an upgrade from 5.5 to 5.7, after which phpmyadmin is broken.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have selected the database from the left frame? so you should have the screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO3Xl.png)

Comment: it throws the error before I reach what your screenshot shows. However, when I press the + next to the db, and select a table, it does show the db on top. Then, if I wish to browse to "structure" or "search", it will again throw me the error

Comment: it's very strange it tries to execute this select statement almost wherever I want to browse in phpmyadmin

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121383/mysql-issue-table-data-dictionary-character-sets-doesnt-exist

Comment: I indeed saw that post, but the solutions of the comments do not seem to help me. Default languages are English for me...

Answer (score 0):

Solution as per Jayant's advise here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756908/mysql-database-browsers-not-working-after-upgrade

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force --upgrade-system-tables
```

and restart mysql.