# Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was using sql 5.5 and updated it. After update I am getting error in phpmyadmin.

```
Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist.
```

I try this [stack overflow ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121383/mysql-issue-table-data-dictionary-character-sets-doesnt-exist)

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
```

and then restart my sql but it didn't work for me.

please suggest me.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using now? Which phpMyAdmin version? Are you able to try connecting from the command-line client? What do the MySQL logs say? What exactly is the output when you run the mysql_upgrade command? You might also add -v for more verbose output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL issue: Table 'data\_dictionary.CHARACTER\_SETS' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121383/mysql-issue-table-data-dictionary-character-sets-doesnt-exist)